# Determinar si una frase es oración completiva o relativa

Tags: sintaxis

¿Es la parte en negrita una oración completiva (*exigió que...*) o relativa y se refiere a la palabra *habitación*?

> El joven preguntó si había habitaciones libres, exigió la mejor, **que
>   dispusiera de agua caliente y periódicos**.

Yo tiendo a pensar que es una frase relativa, pero no estoy segura.

Gracias

Comment: Es relativa al sustantivo *habitación* — *exigió la mejor* (= la mejor habitación), *que dispusiera de agua caliente y periódicos* (= cláusula adjetival que modifica al sustantivo *habitación*).

Comment: No sería del todo descabellado considerarlo una frase completiva en el sentido de *El joven preguntó si había habitaciones libres, exigió la mejor, (exigió) que dispusiera de agua caliente y periódicos.* Sería una construcción algo zeugmática, pero no impensable. Lo más probable, sin embargo, es que sea relativa.

Comment: @Yay ¿qué es _zeugmático_?

Comment: @fedorqui Un pequeño giro idiosincrático sobre el sustantivo [*zeugma*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es relativa (cláusula relativa = en relación al sustantivo) a *habitación*,

> (...) ***exigió la mejor*** (= la mejor habitación),
>   ***que dispusiera de agua caliente y periódicos***. (= cláusula adjetival que modifica al sustantivo habitación).

Cuando estas cláusulas caracterizan al sustantivo, suelen ser adjetivales.

Answer (score 1):

Es "adjetiva o de relativo". Prueba a cambiar "que" por "la cual". ¿Funciona? ¿Sí?
Entonces "que" es un relativo. Y su antecedente es "habitación".

Truco: la mejor manera de hacer un análisis sintáctico es SIEMPRE probar a transformar las oraciones...