# La oración "(...) que pudiera mantener a solas con la señora A", ¿es relativa o completiva?

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis, subordinadas

> Pero como la circunstancia es tan pesarosa y comprendo cuán
>   tristemente la ha afectado, me contentaría con la conversación **que
>   pudiera mantener a solas con la señora A**.

¿Qué es lo que "provoca" el uso del subjuntivo en esta frase: el verbo *contentarse* (= el deseo de tener una conversación) o el antecedente hipotético de la oración relativa (la conversación que...)? Y por eso no estoy segura si esto es una oración relativa o completiva.

Muchas gracias

Comment: En este caso es presente, de una situación del momento, que no se enfoca en el futuro. Nota la deferencia entre decir *que **pueda/pudiera**.* La cláusula *que pudiera* (...) añade información del sustantivo abstracto *conversación*.

Comment: @Ustanak desde el momento que añade información sobre el complemento directo, ¿qué tipo de oración sería? Veo que [mencionaste](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17608/1674) que si añade al sujeto es completiva.

Comment: @fedorqui Yo creo que es adjetival, igual como la que respondí con anterioridad. Es como decir (...) *la conversación **amena** con la señora A.*

Comment: @Ustanak ajá, ya veo. Como es un tema nuevo para mí, [intenté responder](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17672/1674) a una de estas. ¿Te importaría echarle una ojeada para ver si lo entendí bien? Y si te animas a responder esta pregunta, mejor aún, así aprendemos todos : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Me contentaría con la conversación que pudiera mantener a solas con la señora A.

En el caso específico de la partícula de la pregunta *"que pudiera mantener a solas con la señora A"* tenemos un ejemplo de una oración de relativo. Una oración de relativo es aquella que aporta información adicional de un sustantivo. En este caso la oración:

> que pudiera mantener a solas con la señora A

nos da información adicional sobre la conversación. De la misma manera son oraciones de relativo las siguientes:

- El gimnasio *a donde voy todos los días* ...
- El auto *que me regaló mi padre* ...
- Los días *que son mas cortos en invierno* ...
- La charla *cuya culminación sería inesperada* ...

  ---

El en la oración que propones también hay una oración subordinada que no es de relativo. A pesar de que la he visto referida como oración completiva, no estoy seguro que esta definición sea del todo rigurosa. En el ejemlo:

> la conversación que pudiera mantener a solas con la señora A

es una oración subordinada sustantiva de objeto directo. En este caso la preposición **con** introduce la oración subordinada.

---

Finalmente, para complicar aun más las cosas, te diré que las oraciones de relativo también son oraciones subordinadas pero de tipo adjetivo. Existen tres tipos de oraciones subordinadas:

1. Adverbiales
2. Sustantivas
3. Adjetivas

De éstas solo las adjetivas se conocen como de relativo. El truco es que las oraciones adjetivas se refieren exclusivamente a un sustantivo. Las otras dos, se refieren a una oración bimembre. Entonces

> la conversacion

por ser unimembre (solo tiene sujeto), su oración subordinada resulta ser adjetiva (o de relativo).

De la misma forma:

> me contentaría

por ser bimembre (tiene sujeto y predicado) su oración subordinada solo puede ser adverbial o sustantiva.

Comment: _El gimnasio *a **dónde** voy todos los días*_ me parece incorrecto. Juraría que es _donde_, sin tilde ([dichoso markdown :D](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39120561/1983854)).

Comment: Estás en lo cierto. Había tomado en cuenta una regla que dice que se puede escribir con tilde cuando se usa como presposición o cuando se escribe en sentido interrogativo o exclamativo. Ej. *Ese gimnasio dónde quiera que esté* es correcto. Pero también existe otra regla que dice que cuando introducen oraciones relativas se han de escribir sin tilde. Ya que el ejemplo que puse no está ni en sentido exclamativo o interrogativo tengo que darte la razón.